# Make LCD reflective

Tags: lcd, display

If I don't care about dim light or darkness, can I make an LCD-display sunlight readable by removing it's backlight and replace it by a mirroring surface, followed by a diffusor?

Comment: There are small LCD displays that are reflective rather than transmissive.  Are you talking about a little 7-segment display, or graphics?

Comment: So - kinda like a pocket calculator ... ?

Comment: check out the petrol pump display next time you fuel up your vehicle

Comment: I am mainly talking about a smartphone-screen (IPS, LCD I'd say are the only ones that could work)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes. Fundamentally the only difference between a backlit display and a reflective display is that the former has a light at the back and the latter has a reflective surface at the back. Of course, performance will be variable, depending on how the rest of the layers stack up.

[image]

But it's certainly possibly to get the behaviour, if not performance, of the various modes (reflective, backlit, transmissive, transflective, etc.) simply by swapping out layers. On some screens you can even just flip one of the layers around to switch from one mode to another, although the results are likely to be far from ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Purpose of my question would be to transform a mobile phone to as-perfect-as-possible sunlight readability. Are todays smartphone-screens (LCD?) still built the same way?

Comment: @Raphael Most big-name modern phones seem to use OLED screens, which you cannot do this kind of alteration to as they work on a fundamentally different principle.

Comment: I know. However, there are several phones with LCD-screens, f.e. the Nokia 8. I only don't know if the layers are in any way separable